# Run WPF Application and in that call other wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

i have two WPF Application say WPFApplication1 and WPFApplication2 , WPFApplication1 has reference of WPFApplication2 , now i am calling one class of WPFApplication2 in WPFApplication1 using reference, and from WPFApplication2 class creating App class instance of WPFApplication2 , so i am facing issue like below
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wkJJ.png)

Please help me out with this, THanks in Advance

Comment: I've answer the question. But are you shure that you not need a Dialog? Instead of call other application?

Comment: yes i need a dialog.i am trying to accessing Application.Current object basically but it gives object from which it's getting called not the one currently it's reside.

Comment: Please, Vote my answer due to it's answers for you current question. And create one more for "Dialog".

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Process.Start` and `ProcessStartInfo` 
Here is an example for Console application. But there are not different how to start other application.

By `ProcessStartInfo` you can specify many things like Are you has to wait it? Or run without waiting. Is you want to redirect output? And so one.

using System.Diagnostics;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        LaunchCommandLineApp();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Launch the application with some options set.
    /// </summary>
    static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
    {
        // For the example
        const string ex1 = "C:\\";
        const string ex2 = "C:\\Dir";

        // Use ProcessStartInfo class
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = "dcm2jpg.exe";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2;

        try
        {
            // Start the process with the info we specified.
            // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
             // Log error.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will run as exe all i wanted to fetch that Application.Current context for seperate application. i was running one Application from that was invoking second application object, but it was giving me same domain error, so i resolved with directly calling MainWindow object without initiating Application object.